# Define $S^0 = \{T \in \mathcal{L}(\textsf V,\textsf W): T(x) = 0 \textrm{ for all } x \in S\}$, then prove the following

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Let $\textsf V$ and $\textsf W$ be vector spaces, and let $S$ be a subset of $\textsf V$. Define 
$$S^0 = \{T \in \mathcal{L}(\textsf V,\textsf W): T(x) = 0 \textrm{ for all } x \in S\}.$$
Prove the following:

a) $S^0$ is a subspace of $\mathcal{L}(\textsf V,\textsf W)$.

b) If $S_1$ and $S_2$ are subsets of $\textsf V$ such that $S_1$ $\subseteq$ $S_2$, then $S_2^0$ $\subseteq$ $S_1^0$.

I'm not sure where to start with this one. I'm just very confused. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's not helpful to say that you don't know where to start. This is an exercise from a textbook (or similar source); what material precedes it that could be useful? The first part is just verifying a definition; what problem did you run into when you tried to do that?

Comment: The answer below helped. I was struggling with figuring out what the elements of this subset would be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For (a) you have to check that if $T_1,T_2 \in S^0$ and $\lambda \in \Bbb R$, then $T_1+\lambda T_2 \in S^0$.  This is true because $$ (T_1+\lambda T_2)|_S = T_1|_S + \lambda T_2|_S = 0 + \lambda \cdot 0 = 0.$$For (b), you have to show that if $T$ annihilates $S_2$, then it annihilates $S_1$. But this is obvious since $S_1\subseteq S_2$ (in other words, if $T$ annihilates $S_2$, it will also annihilate anything inside $S_2$).